# How to use User-Input to address specific variables in Pascal (Eval/Exec?)

Tags: delphi, exec, eval, user-input, pascal

I'm trying to do something very specific in the fractal program [Apophysis 7X](http://apophysis-7x.org/), the scripting language in use is Pascal (the project is [written in Delphi](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/apophysis7x/svn/trunk/)).

What I want to do:
Write a script that can dynamically address certain variables. In the program I have so called transforms, and each transform has multiple variations, new variations can be added by plugins, hence I do not know all names there could be.

The variables are addressed like this:

```
Transform.Linear:=Sin(Pi*(FrameCount / FrameQuantity));
```

The Variation that is to be changed might not be Linear though, but a dozen other words, like Spherical or Zcone.
If eval would work I'd assume the solution to be something like this:

```
VariationName:=User-Input;
eval('Transform.' + VariationName + ':=Sin(Pi*(FrameCount / FrameQuantity));')
```

As far as I know though, there is no such thing like eval or exec in Pascal (Tried: Eval/eval/Exec/exec). Searching other sites and the internet didn't turn up any ideas either.

So the question is how can I use the User-Input to address those variables? Obviously:

```
Transform.'User-Input':=Sin(Pi*(FrameCount / FrameQuantity));
```

will not work. Since I don't know all names up front I can't just use an array or anything static either. Any ideas would be greatly welcome.

Comment: Pascal is not a scripting language. That is the root of your problem, there is no interpreter to call with eval()

Comment: Yeah, I feared something along those lines, I'd knew how to do it in Ruby, and could figure it out in Python. But Pascal apparently can not, it's frustrating because it's so easy in text... Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Usually 90% of the eval wishes can be solved with a simple expression evaluator and an array of name,value pairs.   Of which there are at least a dozen, if not two for Delphi/FPC. Don't be the "the only tool I know is a hammer" type.

Comment: That'd usually be they way I'd go, but I can't do that because I don't know the contents of the Array beforehand, it'd work for the main amount of Variations but not for the rest, and that's where things would get patchy.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). Delphi does have support for it (they call it Extended [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)). Give a look at the functions [IsPublishedProp](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TypInfo.IsPublishedProp) and [SetPropValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TypInfo.SetPropValue).

Comment: I think that OP asks how to declare and use a variable for a variation object in that Apophysis 7X script (it uses its own, limited scripting language), not how to modify that Apophysis 7X project itself.

Comment: Object Pascal itself doesn't have support for Reflection (that's where the Extended comes from). If not Delphi, there's no way to do it (as far as I know).

Comment: Object Pascal does have RTTI (something that is reflection in Java, sources seems to differ on if that is a general term or Java specific), but only for published fields and properties and their associated types.  In Delphi 2010, much more RTTI is generated with a new interface (unit RTTI). This is called and extended RTTI, and  doubled the size of binaries unfortunately, since boundless RTTI is not a good thing in a natively compiled language.

Comment: You're absolutely right. What I was trying to say is that I think Object Pascal's RTTI specifies Type Introspection only (you can see stuff, but you can't actually change anything). The Extended part of Delphi 2010 is the addition of Reflection.

Comment: @Rigel No, even old style RTTI supported reflection but it was limited since its entire design remit was to support component streaming

Comment: @David Cool! Didn't know it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: David is right for the old published method RTTI, but there is also some interface related RTTI since D7. That was meant for foreign interfacing I assume (SOAP? CORBA? COM dispinterface implementations?)

Comment: Thanks for going that deep into the matter. I guess though that means there is no way for me to properly do it with Pascal and Apophysis. Even if I could somehow program it inside of the script, it's supposed to stay mostly human readable even for people that don't really program themselves, so yeah...
I will look for some alternatives with Ruby, Python, or something that properly supports what I want to do.